# How to Pre-Generate an Ethereum Contract Adress

Tags: python, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3py

I'm trying to generate the address of a contract before its deployed. This is my code, using Web3.py:

```
sender = w3.eth.default_account
expected_address = w3.keccak(rlp.encode([sender, 0]))[12:]
print("Expected address:")
print(expected_address.hex())
```

But I'm not generating the same address as when I deploy the contract. sender has not yet sent a transaction, so the nonce should be zero. I saw a snippet of code using a normalize_transaction function on the sender address but I was unable to find out where to import it from, is that what I'm missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. This site is not a code-writing or tutoring service, it is best used when you have a specific problem with written code. Your question, reads like "Can someone code this for me" or "Show me a tutorial or information on how to code this" which are off-topic for Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour], read [what are you asking].

Comment: if you want to know **ahead of time** the addresses for smart contracts when they do get **subsequently** deployed, you need to use `CREATE2`, and the code above indicates you're using `CREATE`. See EIP-1014.

Answer (score 2):

- `CREATE` uses `keccak256(rlp([sender, nonce]))` to work out the deployed address
- `CREATE2` uses `keccak256(0xff ++ address ++ salt ++ keccak256(init_code))` to work out the deployed address

Reference: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1014.md

Implementation using "Example 4" from EIP-1014:

```py
from eth_utils import to_checksum_address
from web3 import Web3

pre = bytes.fromhex('ff')
address = bytes.fromhex('00000000000000000000000000000000deadbeef')
salt = bytes.fromhex('0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000cafebabe')
init_code_hash = Web3.keccak(bytes.fromhex('0xdeadbeef'))
result_hash = Web3.keccak(pre + address + salt + init_code_hash)
result_address = to_checksum_address(result_hash[12:].hex())
```

Comment: So there is no need to use the nonce? Also, how do you determine what hex to use for the salt and init_code_hash?

Comment: Your 2nd question is (part of) the answer to your 1st question ;) ... (1) Yes, the nonce isn't involved. (2) This line from EIP-1014 explains the difference between `CREATE` and `CREATE2`: *(smart contract) addresses that do not exist yet on-chain but can be relied on to only possibly eventually contain code that has been created by a particular piece of init code*, in other words, you can work out the deployed address **before** actually submitting the deployment transaction for that smart contract.

Comment: @bugiz Thanks, but I still don't quite understand where the values used to create "salt" and "init_code_hash" are coming from. Can you explain why the strings "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000cafebabe" and "0xdeadbeef" are used?

Comment: The init code is produced by the compiler:
The init_code is the code that, when executed, produces the runtime bytecode that will be placed into the state, and which typically is used by high level languages to implement a 'constructor'. 
-- Ref: https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1014.md#clarifications

Comment: The salt is something that you can choose. At random ... or you can choose a specific salt that yields a particular "vanity" address.